# From Curl to Goutte (with proxy)

Tags: curl, proxy, guzzle, goutte

I'm currently trying to use the proxy solution Crawlera with Goutte.
It's OK with curl, cf. http://doc.scrapinghub.com/crawlera.html#php
But not OK with Goutte (no error, content is not returned).

Here is my code :

```
$client = new Client();
$guzzle = $client->getClient();
$guzzle->setDefaultOption('headers', array('X-Crawlera-Use-HTTPS' => 1));
$guzzle->setDefaultOption('proxy', 'proxy.crawlera.com:8010');
$guzzle->setDefaultOption('auth', array([API_KEY], '', 'basic'));
$client->setClient($guzzle);
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
```

Any ideas ? Thanks ?

NB : It's OK when I'm using the solution proxyMesh

```
$client = new Client();
$guzzle = $client->getClient();
$guzzle->setDefaultOption('proxy', 'http://uk.proxymesh.com:31280');
$guzzle->setDefaultOption('auth', array([user], [password], 'basic'));
$client->setClient($guzzle);
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you linked, the API_KEY is the password for your authentication.  As shown, you are using the API_KEY as the username.

```
$guzzle->setDefaultOption('auth', [ null, API_KEY ]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been searching for this over Stack Overflow for some time! This works very well on Goutte, which uses Guzzle internally.